# ADFS Error page

Tags: adfs

I have a claim rule in ADFS 2.0 for a relying party. The rule basically checks if the user is in an AD group. Is it possible in ADFS to specify a custom error page, say "Unauthorized", such that when a user, who is not in the AD group as mentioned in the rule, is redirected to a custom unauthorized error page?

Answer (score 0):

This is supported in 2012R2 where you can add per-RP custom authorization messages. Within this, you can add messages with a link for remediation. See "Customer a relying party authorization message" at [ADFS Error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764941/adfs-error-page).

You can customize in ADFS 2.0, but would have to look at the error.aspx page and right code for it. I believe you get the RP ID in the error page and you can take action on it in code.

Thanks
//Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: The link is somewhat recursive :-) - did you mean https://technet.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/dn280950.aspx